# Fiitro - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou tentando criar relatórios.
Nunca fiz isso antes pois então toda e qualquer ajuda é muito bem-vinda.
Minha tabela inicia na coluna "A" e vai até a coluna "BL". São 64 colunas.
Quero filtrar todos os clientes sem repetição e essa lista de clientes apareça em um ListView.
Quando eu der um clique duplo no nome dentro da listView, esse abra a UserFormClientes com todas as textBox preenchidas.

Tenho esse código onde tento filtrar
Todavia não funciona, precisa de uns ajustes.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem certeza que o erro ```Object doesn't support this property or method``` está acontecendo em ```linha = linha + 1```? Eu chutaria que o erro está em uma das duas linhas anteriores. É realmente essa a linha que fica amarela? No print, você não pintou a linha errada, ou avançou uma linha antes de printar?

Answer (score 0):

Após inserir a linha com a coleção **ListItems**, você adiciona as colunas com a coleção **ListSubItems**.

altere a linha

```
li.ListItems.Add Text:=Sheets("Customers").Cells(linha, 2).Value
```

Para:

```
li.ListSubItems.Add Text:=Sheets("Customers").Cells(linha, 2).Value
```

Comment: As linhas são idênticas. Mudar o que?

Comment: Não são, no seu comando está li.ListItems.Add no que eu pedi é ListSubItems.Add